# Set PrimeFaces horizontal scrollable datatable width

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to set a PrimeFaces horizontal scrollable datatable width. It makes very tight, if set `scollable=true`. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTableA"
             value="#{citizensManagedBean.listcitizens}"
             emptyMessage="No records found"
             style="width: 80em;"
             scrollable="true"
             scrollWidth="150em"
             var="data">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fiddling around with the CSS and see if it fixes the problem. Like try scrollWidth="150" or try setting a width on your columns. You could also try adding table-layout: fixed; to your css.